# Wrapping std::map and provide pointer to element

Tags: c++11, dictionary, iterator

I am using a library which offers a function `foo(Widget*)`.

My Widgets are stored in

```
struct WidgetManager {

  std::map<int, Widget> dict;

  ??? getWidget(int id);

}
```

Originally I stored (raw) Widget pointers in the `std::map` just because it was convenient to pass them to foo.
If I want to store the actual Widgets in the map, what should the return type of `getWidget` be so that I can pass a pointer of the Widget to foo?

I am compelled to make it of type iterator, but I don't like that I have to access `itr->second` to get the Widget(pointer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `&` just before you pass your widget to the `foo(Widget*)` function to get a pointer to it.

```
struct WidgetManager {
  std::map<int, Widget> dict;
  Widget& getWidget(int id);
}
```

usage

```
WidgetManager wm;
//...
Widget& w = wm.getWidget(id);
foo(&w);
//...
```